# MySQL : "How to store row from one table(link) to multiple(cateogry) tables."

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not sure if i phrased my title correctly , but what i want to achieve is :

From table `link` that contain `link.id` , `link.loc` , `link.title` , `link.desc` , `link.cat_id`

have it connect to second table `category` where categories are defined. Each `link` can have multiple `category` , and each `category` can have multiple `link`.

I managed to do this , by having `category` table contain : `category.id` , `category.name` , `category.desc` and foreign key `link.cat_id` on `category.id`.

And simply insert same `link` row in multiple `category` rows. But i am certain this is not best practice and there is better solution. I have read some questions and answeres here and look into MySQL tutorials , yet i can't wrap my mind over this.

If someone can put concrete example of how this can be achieved i will be greatful.

Thanks for your time reading this.

Comment: [Junction Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) is what you are after

Comment: Might be , il look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using a "bridging table", just with fields cat_id and link_id, unless you expect to get any combinations repeated, set both fields of the "bridging table" to be foreign keys

Comment: I think i get the idea what u are saying, gonna go try to configure it that way.

Comment: Ok i did it and it works , however i have done it with 3 columns , 1st one being Unique ID Primary Key , why did u recommend only two ?

Comment: The cat_id and link_id fields in the "bridging table" are sufficient when they're both set to be foreign key. It'll prevent the insertion of duplicate rows

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!